# Jquery UI - Create duplicate DOM element then add and remove class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a widget, known in the car industry as a squashed frog. its basically an image of a flattened car with icons that show were the damage is located. i have a list of HTML image icons that i want to be duplicated when the user clicks so a copy of this HTML icon will be placed within a container div, and then it can be dragged to the location on the image of the car where the damage is located.

Once the copy has been created and is a child of the parent container div, i want to add the class **"draggable"** so it can be dragged, and then remove the class **"frog-key"** so it wont create another duplicate of this copy when clicked.

the problem is im struggling to remove the **"frog-key"** class once the element has been clicked...

here is my code...

```
    <!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // when an element is clicked, a duplicate is created that can be dragged.
        // where it is placed is where the coordinates will be saved

        $(".frog-key").click(function () {

            var copy = $(this).clone(true);

            // add a unique ID
            copy.attr("id", copy.attr("data-type") + "-1");

            // remove class frog-key as we dont want a duplicate of this copy
            copy.removeClass("frog-key");

            // add the class draggable  - so it can be dragged - jquery UI
            copy.addClass("draggable");

            // add this copy to the container div
            $("#squashed-frog-container").append(copy);

        });

    })
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="squashed-frog" class="large">
<div id="squashed-frog-container">
    <img id="squashed-frog-art" src="/Content/Design/img/ART_squashed_frog_large.png">
</div>
<ul class="unstyled" id="squashed-frog-key">
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key dent" data-type="Dent_Bodyshop"></span>Dent <small>(Bodyshop)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key dent-repair" data-type="Dent_SmartRepair"></span>Dent <small>(Smart Repair)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key scratch" data-type="Scratch_Bodyshop"></span>Scratch <small>(Bodyshop)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key scratch-repair" data-type="Scratch_SmartRepair"></span>Scratch <small>(Smart Repair)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key chip" data-type="Scratch_Chip"></span>Chip</li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key multi-chip" data-type="Multiple_Chips"></span>Multiple Chips</li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key paint" data-type="Paint_OffColour"></span>Paint <small>(Off Colour)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key paint-repair" data-type="Paint_PreviousRepair"></span>Paint <small>(Previous Repair)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key paint-fallout" data-type="Paint_Fallout"></span>Paint <small>(Fallout)</small></li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key rust" data-type="Rust"></span>Rust</li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key wheel-Scuff" data-type="Wheel_Scuff"></span>Wheel Scuff</li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key sidewall" data-type="Sidewall_Damage"></span>Sidewall Damage</li>
    <li><span class="pointer sprite frog-key broken" data-type="Broken"></span>Broken</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing one line (plus I had to reinitialise draggable in the click event - but that may have been the fiddle's fault):

```
copy.unbind("click");
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

When you cloned the element, it retained it's click event. .frog-key was actually removed as planned, but is not evaluated each time; once the page is loaded the event is attached to the element and its clones and remains so until specifically unbound.

I hope this helps.